# How to See Full Header in Outlook Mail Online? (2018)

Tags: outlook.com

I received this phishing email and I want to see its full header. How can I do this on outlook.com?

Here is a screenshot of what I see
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you're looking for is actually in the message menu next to the "Reply" button.

[image: Reply and menu]

Click the down arrow to open the menu.

[image: message menu]

Choose "View message source"

[image: message source]

That'll give you the raw email message, including all the headers.